# Should i close oracle connection after success callback?

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, node-oracledb

I'm using oracledb to get new oracle connections in my nodejs app but I noticed that in `v$session` table many connections/sessions are logged like 'INACTIVE'.

When I get an error my app always will release the connection with `this.doReleaseConn(conn, !autoCommit);` but I don't know for sure if this treatment should be used, also, with success callback.

Comment: How many users does your application serve?

Comment: In dev enviroment, likely 5 but in production this scale for 1,000,000 +

Comment: For a million users (or even much fewer) you should configure a connection pool and re-use sessions for different users. Constantly creating and dropping thousands of connections will kill your application.

Comment: My pool is setted with MIN | MAX | TIMEOUT | POOL_INCREMENT | CACHE | MAX_RETRIES -> 2 | 40 | 5 | 60 | 4000 | 5 . And i get some logs with  ORA-02391 and TNS connection closed but it's not constant

Comment: Not all those parameters are for the node-oracledb connection pool.  Can you share more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the node-oracledb [Connection Pooling doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpooling):

> Connections must be released with connection.close() when no longer needed so they can be reused. Make sure to release connections in all codes paths, include error handlers.

The point about a connection pool is the connections between the Node.js tier and the database remain open and ready for quick reuse.  So you will see evidence of this in the V$ views.